# converting 1 million line code base from 32-bit to 64-bit

Tags: c, migration, middleware, 32bit-64bit

Approach 1, Direct Conversion:

This approach involves directly converting the codebase from 32-bit to 64-bit by modifying the existing code. I know this approach is time-consuming because our code base is 1 million lines of C code.

Could someone kindly suggest a step-by-step approach for identifying the specific area in the code where the issue related to the 64-bit conversion lies?

I have looked at static code analyzers tools and compiler flags

Comment: If it's well written and doesn't make any assumptions about pointer width, just recompiling should be enough. Of course, in the real world...

Comment: Did you mean your approach 1 is manually reading through 1 million lines of code and  find any issues just by looking at the code? Sounds like an impossible mission...

Comment: Hello @JamesZ can you please suggest another approach?

Comment: I think it's very related to how low the processing level goes, and how standard the codebase is. A few examples: a `char * p;` could *survive* the transition, but if for any reason someone did a `uint32_t address = (uint32_t)p;` then you're in trouble.

Comment: You might try to run some static code analyzers. They might find such things like using plain integers instead of integer types where the size is defined like `int32_t` vs `int`. Or they could find conversions between pointers and integers. If you are lucky, they might find them even if the compiler warnings are silenced using casts. Of course, if some magic numbers like `4` are used for sizes in memory allocation instead of `sizeof <pointer>` then you might run out of luck...

Comment: Just compile it. If the transition isn't easy, the code is bad. (I commonly write code which i use on AMD64 and ARM32 and i never had any problem in this regard). Enable almost all compiler warnings and eliminate all warnings by writing good code. Maybe you will find some additional minor things (like using the wrong `printf()` length modifier) but you should be able to fix them (because the compiler tells you to do it). And then test your code.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me, Which type of static code analyzer tool can assist in identifying migration warnings?

Comment: if you convert all the existing uses of int and unsigned it to int32_t and uint32_t then your math should run identically. You should get warnings whenever you read something from a library call that is actually 64 bit, so you know to convert that variable to 64bit. Fix all warnings!